# How can i differentiate normal push notification from rich push notification?

Tags: push-notification, urbanairship.com, richpush

I currently integrated Urban Airship in my application, i implemented simple push notification and i also implemented the rich push notification, now both of them works properly, when i send a normal notification it is received correctly, and when i send a rich push message bundled with a push notification it is also received correctly,
but i want to know how can i differentiate if that notification is just a normal notification or if it is a notification that is bundle with a rich push message, i cannot figure out how to do this because both push notification call the same methods,

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello @Alexy Ibrahim
I am using Urban Airship sdk for test rich push notification.
As u mentioned that u received push for both sample and rich.
but i did not receive push for rich push unless i can get that messages from UA database.
Please tell me how to get push for rich push.